# How get intent data in internal class

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a activity where I have some data from previous activity:

```
final int pictureId = intent.getIntExtra("my.picture.id",0);
    final String headerId = intent.getStringExtra("my.header.id");
    final String bodyId = intent.getStringExtra("my.body.id");
```

In this activity I have private class where I want to get this data like pictureId etc., but I don't know how. How I can get this data in my class.

Comment: if you have internal class(not an activity) in your activity then declare global ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Privtate Class's constructor add a parameter.

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

PrivateClass mPrivateClass

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mPrivateClass= new PrivateClass(getIntent());
}
```

Your Private Class will look like this.

```
private class PrivateClass
{
    PrivateClass(Intent mIntent)
    {
       final int pictureId = intent.getIntExtra("my.picture.id",0);
       final String headerId = intent.getStringExtra("my.header.id");
       final String bodyId = intent.getStringExtra("my.body.id");
    }
}
```